# React Router Dom not rendering any component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a very simple project and react router dom is not rendering components. Sometimes it renders the component for first route but then it doesn't render.

Here's the code for App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import store from "./store";
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import { IntroJm } from './components/intro/jm';
import { IntroNfc } from './components/intro/nfc';
import { IntroTxn } from './components/intro/txn';

import './assets/sass/main.scss';
import './static/css/main.scss';
import './static/css/pure.min.scss';
import './App.scss';

let browserHistory = createHistory();

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    browserHistory.push("/intro/jm");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Route path="/intro/jm" component={IntroJm} />
              <Route path="/intro/nfc" component={IntroNfc} />
              <Route path="/intro/txn" component={IntroTxn} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

All the route components are simple component with a span tag only.

Please help

Comment: Not working. I tried this already. But since its react-router-dom, it is not needed anyway

Comment: code looks fine to me.. can you get rid of that componentDidMount function and navigate using Link components?

Comment: I tried that also, in that case the first component gets rendered where I navigate for first time. But other components don't render.

Comment: Something else must be going on that's not specific to react-router.. no errors in the console?

Comment: No errors to console. Although this time it worked with links. But what's wrong with navigating on componentDidMount? How should I enforce to go to a particular route whenever user hits my domain?

Comment: no nothing wrong, just wanted to make sure that wasn't the source of the problem. react-router-dom also ships with a `Redirect` component. it's a little strange to use but makes it useful for programattically navigating based on the current state

Comment: @azium - Ok, I have made a history module for myself. I am manipulating browser history on some actions and localstorage values, like user was on intro screen but now he is on home page and pressing back button of phone he should not go back to intro screen. Also intro screen is just for first usage of website. Now I am using npm's history module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/history. This history module of mine is causing problems. Because removing it and using simple Links and Redirect, my app working fine. But I can't achieve what I want. Do u know any good alternative to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you can't achieve? Maybe make another question and post the link to it here

Comment: @azium - Please look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508625/react-router-dom-not-listening-to-changes-made-to-route-by-htmls-pushstate-meth

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping your component with WithRouter and then changing the route with `this.props.history.push()`

Try

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import {withRouter} 'react-router';

import store from "./store";

import { IntroJm } from './components/intro/jm';
import { IntroNfc } from './components/intro/nfc';
import { IntroTxn } from './components/intro/txn';

import './assets/sass/main.scss';
import './static/css/main.scss';
import './static/css/pure.min.scss';
import './App.scss';

let browserHistory = createHistory();

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.push("/intro/jm");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Route path="/intro/jm" component={IntroJm} />
              <Route path="/intro/nfc" component={IntroNfc} />
              <Route path="/intro/txn" component={IntroTxn} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this answer. Did it help

Comment: I know this answer is a year old, but it worked for me! Thanks! But I just included `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` not `react-router` like in the answer.