# React Router Dom not listening to changes made to route by HTML's pushState method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React Router Dom not listening to changes made to route by HTML's pushState method. And therefore its not rendering components supposed to be rendered for a those routes. Its highly important that I have full control over routes.

It has advance use cases. I have a history stack of like this -

```
['/home', '/about', '/status', '/info']
```

Now the '/info' route has a button that says go back to home and go back to status. After clicking those buttons I should travel back to history of pushStates rather than pushing one more state in pushState stack.

The best approach I though was to install 'history' module from npm as it has several good features. Internally it uses HTML5's pushState only. But with react-router, it's not working. Changing pushState with this history module doesn't render React component.

Please help me on this. Any solution or alternative would be welcomed.

### EDIT:

my App.js is rendering this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/intro/jm" component={IntroJm} />
          <Route path="/intro/nfc" component={IntroNfc} />
          <Route path="/intro/txn" component={IntroTxn} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </Provider>
```

And I am trying to do the following:

```
window.history.pushState({},"JM-Intro","/intro/jm");
```

This is not happening. Actually pushing state is not happening in any possible way in my react application. I also tried using 'history' module of npm. That module and its apis are working but it won't render react component for that particular route.

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Comment: @StephenL - I have included the code

Comment: Any solutions so far?